# Getting a hierarchial multilevel index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, multi-level

I am trying to createa  multilevel index in pandas but when I do a print of hte dataframe, I see something like this.

```
                                           ask   bid
time                type mat        strk            
2014-03-31 13:30:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  32.0  30.6
2014-03-31 13:35:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  32.8  31.2
2014-03-31 13:40:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  31.9  29.9
2014-03-31 13:45:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  31.6  30.1
2014-03-31 13:50:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  32.6  31.2
2014-03-31 13:55:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  33.6  32.1
2014-03-31 14:00:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  34.4  33.0
2014-03-31 14:05:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  33.5  31.9
2014-03-31 14:10:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  34.0  32.2
.....
```

The above is a result of

```
df.set_index(['time', 'type', 'mat', 'strk'], inplace=True)
```

Now I would have expected to see something more hierarchial like this

```
                                           ask   bid
time                type mat        strk            
2014-03-31 13:30:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  32.0  30.6
                                    1860  aaaa  bbbb
                         2014-05-17 1850  xxxx  yyyy
                                    1860  xxxx  yyyy
                    P    2014-04-19 1850  mmmm  nnnn
                                    1860  aaaa  bbbb
                         2014-05-17 1850  xxxx  yyyy
                                    1860  xxxx  yyyy 
2014-03-31 13:35:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  32.8  31.2
2014-03-31 13:40:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  31.9  29.9
2014-03-31 13:45:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  31.6  30.1
2014-03-31 13:50:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  32.6  31.2
2014-03-31 13:55:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  33.6  32.1
2014-03-31 14:00:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  34.4  33.0
2014-03-31 14:05:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  33.5  31.9
2014-03-31 14:10:00 C    2014-04-19 1850  34.0  32.2
```

I have a few rows below for the same time - 2014-03-31 13:30:00
But not sure why I dont see this happeniing. Tried without that 'inplace' options. Still i see the same issue. But in a different place, I do see this hierarchial when i do set_index on a different dataframe. Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the dataframe should help

```
df.sort()
```